# How to download and get offline tiles in ionic 3 android app?

Tags: android, ionic3, openlayers-3, offline

I am trying to develop a hybrid ol3 map application using ionic3 with angularjs. I have generated xyz tiles of the map service which I was able to use for online maps. When I tried using them for download to a local directory of mobile and use them I am facing issues. Kindly provide any help which is much appreciated. I I could not trace any errors. Kindly suggest me how to check if any errors to test the maps.

//For downloading the image from server and stores it into mobile directory.

```
this.file.createDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, 'Offline/Maps/custom_', true).then((files) => {
                    this.file.createDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, 'Offline/Maps/custom_/02_02', true).then((files) => {

                    }).catch((err) => {

                    });
                }).catch((err) => {

                });

                const imageURL = 'https://server.com/documents/ionic/path_track/maps/0041_0041.jpeg';
                const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
                const imageName = imageURL.split('/').pop();
                //alert(imageName+"@"+this.file.externalRootDirectory);
                //alert(imageName);
                fileTransfer.download(imageURL, this.file.externalRootDirectory+'Offline/Maps/custom_07/02_02/'+imageName).then((entry) => {
                    //loader.dismiss();
                    //this.showOfflineButton = true;
                }, (error) => {
                    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                        message: 'Map is not downloaded '+JSON.stringify(error),
                        buttons: ['Ok'],
                        enableBackdropDismiss: false,
                        cssClass:'alert-error'
                    });
                    alert.present();
                });
```

//For retrieving image from the mobile directory and to display into mobile app.

```
var config = {
            "bounds": {
                "left" : 68.1060582899974,
                "bottom" : 6.72246026992798,
                "right" : 97.7525939941406,
                "top" : 37.0967391635301
            }
        };

        var bounds = [config.bounds.left, config.bounds.bottom, config.bounds.right, config.bounds.top];

        var resolutions = [
            0.1186495269281333,
            0.0593247634640666,
            0.0296623817320333,
            0.0148311908660167,
            0.0074155954330083,
            0.0037077977165042,
            0.0018538988582521,
            0.000926949429126,
            0.000463474714563,
            0.0002317373572815,
            0.0001158686786408,
            0.0000579343393204,
            0.0000289671696602,
            0.0000144835848301,
            0.000007241792415
        ];

        var projection_epsg_no = 4326
        var layername = 'seamless_xyz1';

        var tileGrid = new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
            extent: bounds,
            resolutions: resolutions,
            origin: ol.extent.getTopLeft(bounds),
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            tileSize: [256, 256]
        });

        var view = new ol.View({
            extent: [55.948355423604156, 4.853611184459009, 101.73937104860416, 38.07626743445901],
            zoom: 10,
            center: [78.48695, 17.41217],
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            resolutions: resolutions
        });

        var tms_source = new ol.source.XYZ({
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            tileGrid: tileGrid,
            url: this.file.externalRootDirectory+'/Offline/Maps/custom_{z}/{x}/{-y}.jpeg'
            //url: this.file.externalRootDirectory+'/Offline/Maps/custom_07/02_02/0041_0043.jpeg' (If I am giving static image name then its coming fine but not able to do it dynamically.)
        });

        var basegroup = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: tms_source,
            extent: bounds
        });

var mapview;

if(this.Source_lat == undefined || this.Source_long == undefined){
            this.current_location1 = 'Location is not available.';
            mapview = new ol.View({
                projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                center: [82.491,21.899],
                extent: [66.2329, 7.68083, 98.2223, 39.03874],
                maxZoom:16,
                minZoom: 8,
                zoom: 8
            });
        }else{
            this.current_location1 = this.Source_lat+', '+this.Source_long;
            mapview = new ol.View({
                projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                center: [this.Source_long,this.Source_lat],
                extent: [66.2329, 7.68083, 98.2223, 39.03874],
                maxZoom:10,
                minZoom: 10,
                zoom: 10
            });
        }
        map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'offline_map',
            controls: ol.control.defaults({
                zoom: false,
                attribution: false,
                rotate: false
            }),
            layers: [basegroup, jsonLayer_net1, jsonLayer_net],
            overlays: [jsonoverlay],
            view: mapview
        });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't get any errors? Maybe your app doesn't have File permissions, or you can't write in the directory you are trying to use?

Comment: I have given file permission and able to download the images and show the tiles manually (By giving image name). But unable to download it dynamically and visualize the same.